# Java pairs of symbols program

Tags: java, stack

Using stack data structure(s): If the input file is not balanced, the un-balance cause and the in-file localization details will be supplied. For flexibility reasons, read the balancing pairs of symbols from a text file. Test your program by considering the following pairs of symbols: ( ), { }, [ ], /* */

I'm having trouble with the last requirement: /* */

I also can't seem to grasp how to print the in-file localization details? i.e which line number of the text file the error has occured on?

The text file looks like this:

```
(()(()
{}}}{}{
[[[]][][]
((}})){{]
()
[]
{}
[]{}
()()()[]
*/ /*
(a+b) = c
```

The code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class P1 {

    private boolean match = true;

    // The stack
    private java.util.Stack<Character> matchStack = new java.util.Stack<Character>();

    // What to do with a match
    public boolean ismatch() {
        return match && matchStack.isEmpty();
    }

    // Finding a match
    public void add(char c) {
        Character k = leftSide(c);

        if (k == null)
            ;
        else if (k.charValue() == c)
            matchStack.push(k);
        else {
            if (matchStack.isEmpty() || !matchStack.pop().equals(k))
                match = false;
        }
    }

    // Add string values
    public void add(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            add(s.charAt(i));
    }

    // The various symbol pairs
    protected static Character leftSide(char c) {
        switch (c) {
        case '(':
        case ')':
            return new Character('(');
        case '[':
        case ']':
            return new Character('[');
        case '{':
        case '}':
            return new Character('{');
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Main method. Welcome message, read the test file, build the array, print
    // results.
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        // Welcome message
        System.out
                .println("Project #1\n"
                        + "Welcome! The following program ensures both elements of various paired symbols are present.\n"
                        + "Test Data will appear below: \n"
                        + "-------------------------------");

        // Read the file
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "testfile.txt"));
            String str;

            // Keep reading while there is still more data
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                // Line by line read & add to array
                String arr[] = str.split(" ");
                if (arr.length > 0)
                    arrays.add(arr);

                // Let the user know the match status (i.e. print the results)
                P1 mp = new P1();
                mp.add(str);

                System.out.print(mp.ismatch() ? "\nSuccessful Match:\n"
                        : "\nThis match is not complete:\n");
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            in.close();
            // Catch exceptions
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("We're sorry, we are unable to find that file: \n"
                            + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("We're sorry, we are unable to read that file: \n"
                            + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement this would be using a map of stacks such as `Map<String, Stack<Location>>`, where `Location` is a class you create that holds two `int`s (a line number and a character number). That can be your location info. The key (`String`) to this map would be your left side (opener) part of your pairs. Every time you have an opener you look up the appropriate `Stack` in the map and push a new `Location` on it for that opener. Each time you encounter a closer you look up its opener, use the opener to look up the correct `Stack` in the map and then pop it once. The reason I say use `String` for your key is because not all your openers can be represented by `Character` namely your `/*` opener, so a `String` will have to do. Since you can't switch on Strings for your `leftSide(char)` (which will now be `leftSide(String)`) function you'll either have to use `if-else` or use a map (`Map<String, String>`) to create the closer to opener mappings.

When the end of the file is reached the only `Location` objects remaining in the `Stack` objects should be unclosed openers.

Comment: Not that it's too important to your answer, but you actually *can* switch on Strings, as of [JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).